# Multi consumer and single producer which intern is a consumer

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

I have a scenario to fetch a news feed. The first time I request for information it gives me a set of feeds with each feed having a feedId, the feedIds are not in a sequential order(The feedIds are jumbled withIn the set of feeds). The news feed count is limited to a fixed value. If I supply the last fetched feedId from the current set of feeds to the next request it returns me the next set of feeds and this continues. My question here is how to run this kind of problem in a multi-threaded environment?

I have tried getting the first feedID and adding a batchSize of 2000(some random size) between multiple news feed fetcher and I could see two scenarios:

1. There are missing news feed between the last feedId of the last batch and the consequtive batch.
2. Duplicate news feeds with the same Ids.

Can anyone help me with a thought?

Comment: You need to show what you have tried so far for us to be able to help you. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'd say there is no way to use multi threading. If your second request depends on the result of your first request, than those two requests have to be sequential.

Comment: What you are doing makes sense. I suspect the feedIds are not stable and they change between calls. That or the service that gives them to you is not sufficiently stable. Try to replicate your algorithm in a single threaded mode with lots of debug and see if you still see the issues.